# Ansible Idempotence for elasticsearch.yml

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible

New ansible user (v2.3) and pulled playbook for github but not understanding idempotence.  Once elasticsearch is installed and started with playbook, I now want to be able to just modify or add an es_config parm and then rerun playbook expecting an updated elasticsearch.yml config file and elasticsearch restarted. That include_roles elasticsearch however is skipped on rerun and not sure what to modify to change that.

```
ansible-playbook  --ask-become-pass -vv  elk.yml
```

elk.yml

```
---
#
# Playbook to install the ELK stack
#
- hosts: servers
  strategy: debug
  remote_user: ansible
  become: yes
  become_user: root

  tasks:
  - debug: msg="elk main"
  - include_role:
       name: java
       name: elasticsearch
       name: kibana
       name: nginx
       name: logstash

    vars:
      es_instance_name: "node1"
      es_config: {
        discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: "logstash-2, logstash-3",
        network.host: _eno1_,
        cluster.name: logstash,
        node.name: "{{ ansible_hostname }}",
        http.port: 9200,
        transport.tcp.port: 9300,
        node.data: true,
        node.master: true,
        bootstrap.memory_lock: true,
        index.number_of_shards: 3,
        index.number_of_replicas: 1
      }
      es_major_version: "6.x"
      es_version: "6.2.1"
      es_heap_size: "26g"
      es_cluster_name: "logstash"
```

roles/elasticsearch/tasks/main.yml

```
---
- name: os-specific vars
  include_vars: "{{ansible_os_family}}.yml"
  tags:
      - always

- debug: msg="es parms"

- name: check-set-parameters
#  include: elasticsearch-parameters.yml
  include_tasks: elasticsearch-parameters.yml
  tags:
      - always

#- include: java.yml
#  when: es_java_install
#  tags:
#      - java

#- include: elasticsearch.yml
- include_tasks: elasticsearch.yml
```

roles/elasticsearch/tasks/elasticsearch.yml

```
---

- name: Include optional user and group creation.
  when: (es_user_id is defined) and (es_group_id is defined)
  include_tasks: elasticsearch-optional-user.yml

- name: Include specific Elasticsearch
  include_tasks: elasticsearch-Debian.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == 'Debian'
```

roles/elasticsearch/tasks/elasticsearch-Debian.yml

```
---

- set_fact: force_install=no

- set_fact: force_install=yes
  when: es_allow_downgrades

- name: Debian - Install apt-transport-https to support https APT downloads
  become: yes
  apt: name=apt-transport-https state=present
  when: es_use_repository

- name: Debian - Add Elasticsearch repository key
  become: yes
  apt_key: url="{{ es_apt_key }}" state=present
  when: es_use_repository and es_apt_key

- name: Debian - Add elasticsearch repository
  become: yes
  apt_repository: repo={{ item.repo }} state={{ item.state}}
  with_items:
    - { repo: "{{ es_apt_url_old }}", state: "absent" }
    - { repo: "{{ es_apt_url }}", state: "present" }
  when: es_use_repository

- name: Debian - Include versionlock
  include: elasticsearch-Debian-version-lock.yml
  when: es_version_lock

- name: Debian - Ensure elasticsearch is installed
  become: yes
  apt: name=elasticsearch{% if es_version is defined and es_version != "" 
%}={{$
  when: es_use_repository
  register: debian_elasticsearch_install_from_repo
  notify: restart elasticsearch

- name: Debian - Download elasticsearch from url
  get_url: url={% if es_custom_package_url is defined %}{{ 
es_custom_package_ur$
  when: not es_use_repository

- name: Debian - Ensure elasticsearch is installed from downloaded package
  become: yes
  apt: deb=/tmp/elasticsearch-{{ es_version }}.deb
  when: not es_use_repository
  register: elasticsearch_install_from_package
  notify: restart elasticsearch
```

roles/elasticsearch/tasks/elasticsearch-parameters.yml

```
# Check for mandatory parameters

- fail: msg="es_instance_name must be specified and cannot be blank"
  when: es_instance_name is not defined or es_instance_name == ''

- fail: msg="es_proxy_port must be specified and cannot be blank when 
es_proxy_$
  when: (es_proxy_port is not defined or es_proxy_port == '') and 
(es_proxy_hos$

- debug: msg="WARNING - It is recommended you specify the parameter 
'http.port'"
  when: es_config['http.port'] is not defined

- debug: msg="WARNING - It is recommended you specify the parameter 
'transport.$
  when: es_config['transport.tcp.port'] is not defined

- debug: msg="WARNING - It is recommended you specify the parameter 
'discovery.$
  when: es_config['discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts'] is not defined

#If the user attempts to lock memory they must specify a heap size
- fail: msg="If locking memory with bootstrap.memory_lock a heap size must 
be s$
  when: es_config['bootstrap.memory_lock'] is defined and 
es_config['bootstrap.$

#Check if working with security we have an es_api_basic_auth_username and 
es_ap$
- fail: msg="Enabling security requires an es_api_basic_auth_username and 
es_ap$
  when: es_enable_xpack and ("security" in es_xpack_features) and 
es_api_basic_$

- set_fact: file_reserved_users={{ es_users.file.keys() | intersect 
(reserved_x$
 when: es_users is defined and es_users.file is defined and 
(es_users.file.key$

- fail:
 msg: "ERROR: INVALID CONFIG - YOU CANNOT CHANGE RESERVED USERS THROUGH THE$
  when: file_reserved_users | default([]) | length > 0

- set_fact: instance_default_file={{default_file | 
dirname}}/{{es_instance_name$
- set_fact: instance_init_script={{init_script | dirname 
}}/{{es_instance_name}$
- set_fact: conf_dir={{ es_conf_dir }}/{{es_instance_name}}
- set_fact: m_lock_enabled={{ es_config['bootstrap.memory_lock'] is defined 
and$

#TODO - if transport.host is not local maybe error on boostrap checks

#Use systemd for the following distributions:
#Ubuntu 15 and up
#Debian 8 and up
#Centos 7 and up
#Relies on elasticsearch distribution installing a serviced script to 
determine$

- set_fact: use_system_d={{(ansible_distribution == 'Debian' and 
ansible_distri$

- set_fact: instance_sysd_script={{sysd_script | dirname 
}}/{{es_instance_name}$
  when: use_system_d
#For directories we also use the {{inventory_hostname}}-{{ es_instance_name 
}} $

- set_fact: instance_suffix={{inventory_hostname}}-{{ es_instance_name }}
- set_fact: pid_dir={{ es_pid_dir }}/{{instance_suffix}}
- set_fact: log_dir={{ es_log_dir }}/{{instance_suffix}}
- set_fact: data_dirs={{ es_data_dirs | append_to_list('/'+instance_suffix) 
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

formatting issue with include_role. Fixed problem with one role per include as follows:

```
- include_role:
      name: java
- include_role:
      name: elasticsearch
```

and so forth.